# Quirky variable behavior when using alert or prompt

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm learning Javascript and I ran across what I think is some strange behavior.

The simple code below produces the predicted result in the console log.  It shows the phrase Hello!

```
var test = "Hello!";
console.log(test);
```

However this next code snippet returns something that I didn't expect.  It returns undefined in the console log.  In addition the alert executes automatically even though it was never called or used in a function.  Those 2 lines are the entire code.

```
var test = alert("Hello!");
console.log(test);
```

Why did the alert pop up and why was console.log undefined?  I'm trying to get a handle on the mechanics so thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: because alert does not return anything... so it is undefined.

Comment: `alert()` and `console.log()` are *both* functions.  What did you expect `var test = alert("Hello!");` to do?  What do you mean by "[alert] was never called"? You *called* the `alert()` function and saved what it returns into `test`.  Then you *called* the `console.log()` function.

Answer (score 3):

A function call is like any other statement. It doesn't need to be inside another function to be evaluated. If it is outside any function, then it will be evaluated immediately.

When you call `alert("Hello!")` it gets called and it passes its return value to the left hand side.

The `alert` function returns `undefined`, which is why that is what you saw when you logged it.

Comment: I tested what you said with a new function `var test = myFunction();` and sure enough that function automatically ran just like the alert function.  so in Javascript `var test` isn't necessarily waiting to be called by other code.  Code inside variables automatically starts running after the page loads?

Comment: @DR01D: JavaScript executes line-by-line.  When you call a function, that is add `()` after it, it runs.  Compare `alert()`; and `var test = alert();`.  Both run the `alert()`.

Comment: @DR01D — `var test` is assigned **the return value** you get when you **call** the function, not the function itself. To assign the function you would have to use `var test = alert` without the `()`.

Comment: Not always.  The function in this variable doesn't run until it is called, `var test = function(){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello!";`
}  But when I add `test();` it runs.

Comment: @DR01D — That's because you've changed from using a *variable*  (`alert`) which has a function as its value (and which you have `()` after to call that function) to a *function expression* which creates a new function. If you put `()` on the end you would call the function immediately. `var test = function(){ document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello!"; }()`.

Comment: Quentin, holy smokes I just tested it and you were right!  So the () tells it to fire off on the spot.  But without the () it waits to be called.  That helps me so much with basic mechanics.

Answer (score 2):

`window.alert()` call does not return anything when it executes, so it is `undefined`. That `undefined` value is stored in `test` which you write to the console.